# Disable or delete right click menus VBA

Tags: excel, vba, commandbar

Whenever I right click on an excel sheet two menus come up: one with cut, copy, paste, etc. and one with font size, bold, italic etc.

I can customize the first one to have whatever command I want. The problem I have is that I want to DISABLE or DELETE the second one (the one with font size, bold, italic etc.)

I tried going through the entire CommandBars collection but couldnt find the one that I need to delete.
[image: Right Click Disable]
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I take it by the VBA tag that you're trying to achieve this through VBA in something like the `Workbook_Open` Procedure?

Comment: I assume that it needs to be done throught VBA. I have edited the CommandBar using the CommandBar.Delete and CommandBar.Add methods, however, if there is another way to do it I am happy to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently its very easy.

```
Application.ShowMenuFloaties = True
```

Although this does the job, I still dont understand how to manipulate that menu.

Comment: This http://superuser.com/questions/399501/is-there-a-way-to-customize-this-mini-hovering-toolbar says it's not customizable.